# (Excel) Is there a way to automatically highlight the larger number between two?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a two-row chart, I want to highlight, in green, the larger number automatically with an excel formula. Is there a way to do so? Note that the number can be any real number represented in decimal form, and it is guaranteed that there is a number in every cell.

In the picture below, I did this manually, and it looks like this. I really want an excel formula since my chart is rather long. Thank you in advance.

[image]

When I try to add a new rule (from answer), it looks like this:
[image]
What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is Conditional Formatting vs a formula. Setup as follows:
[image]

Comment: Look at my edited question. What do I do now? It only shows minimum/maximum not comparison between 2 numbers

Comment: @CELLSecret there should be an option. On my version it is Conditional Formatting->New Rule->"Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

Comment: As @Euler's Disgraced Stepchild stated you want New Rule then under Select a Rule Type: -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format.